# ERROR: Package signature validation failed. Aborting install. When upgrade the JUNOS

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

My device is EX4300.

I use the bellow command for upgrade the JUNOS version by:

```
request system software add reboot /var/tmp/jinstall-ex-4300-14.1X53-D47.3-demostic-signed.tgz
```

I get the bellow error:

```
NOTICE: Validating configuration against jinstall-ex-4300-14.1X53-D47.3-domestic-signed.tgz.
NOTICE: Use the 'no-validate' option to skip this if desired.
Verify the signature of the new package
verify-sig: cannot validate certs.pem
certificate is not yet valid: /C=US/ST=CA/L=Sunnyvale/O=Juniper Networks/OU=Juniper CA/CN=PackageProductionRSA_2018/emailAddress=ca@juniper.net

ERROR: Package signature validation failed.  Aborting install.
```

the JUNOS version is:

```
admin> show version
fpc0:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Model: ex4300-48t
JUNOS EX  Software Suite [13.2X51-D26.2]
JUNOS FIPS mode utilities [13.2X51-D26.2]
JUNOS Online Documentation [13.2X51-D26.2]
JUNOS EX 4300 Software Suite [13.2X51-D26.2]
JUNOS Web Management [13.2X51-D26.2]
JUNOS py-base-powerpc [13.2X51-D26.2]

{master:0}
```

---

**EDIT-01**

I also have tried:

```
request system software add no-validate /var/tmp/junos-srxsme-10.4R7.5-domestic.tgz
```

Still this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the errors, it's saying "certificate is not yet valid". What that typically means is that your switch doesn't have its clock correctly set to today's date. As a result, from the switch's point of view, the certificate is from the future, and so cannot be valid.

You should start by either setting the date manually, or pointing your switch to your NTP server.